# What is alpha in ridge regression?

Tags: python

What is the parameter alpha in ridge regression and how does it influence the trained regression?

So examples would be helpful for me :)

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What library is this regarding? Have you got a code sample to illustrate?

Comment: can you elaborate on what do you mean by inaccurate? I guess you are referring to ridge regression in scikit learn. You can check out section 6.2.1 in this book, http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf. Note that your alpha from scikit learn is annotated as lambda in the book section

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ridge or Lasso regression is basically Shrinkage(regularization) techniques, which uses different parameters and values to shrink or penalize the coefficients.

When we fit a model, we are asking it to learn a set of coefficients that best fit over the training distribution as well as hope to generalize on test data points as well. Learning those coefficients can be done in various ways and multiple techniques are there to reduce the error in coefficients such as LMS(Least mean Squared), RSS(Residual Sum of Squares).

Now suppose we are training a model using either LMS or RSS, then ridge regression makes use of the extra term which penalizes the results of LMS or RSS towards zero.

So, simply written,

Final error to be corrected = RSS + Ridge Term [OR]
[[image: Equation from ISLR, p215]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Pvj.png)

where Beta1, Beta2 ... are the coefficients for X1, X2... and so on.

Ridge term includes the alpha term, which is nothing but the penalty or the tuning parameter. The whole ridge term is sometimes called the shrinkage penalty term too.

If we fit the data very well, the RSS value is very low. But the second term is close to zero only when B1, B2...Bn values are small. If these are small, then the corresponding X1, X2....Xn values will be small. Thus the impact of Xi term on Y(the output variable) will be less significant compared to some Bj for Xj whose value is large enough.

The alpha term acts as the control parameter, which determines, how much significance should be given to Xi for the Bi coefficient. If Alpha is close to zero, the Ridge term itself is very small and thus the final error is based on RSS alone. If Alpha is too large, the impact of shrinkage grows and the coefficients B1, B2 ... Bn tends to zero.

Choosing the right value helps the model learn the right features and better generalize the coefficients. One of the methods that help in choosing the right value is Cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand everything but I think I can live with that.